# Undefined index : anything?

Tags: php, laravel

When I go to page I get the error : `"Undefined index : img"`.
When I use `var_dump` or `print_r` function , I can see the whole array and its all OK.

My web.php

```
Route::get('/Products/{id}','productcontroller@show');
```

My controller

```
public function show($id)
{
         $products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where id=$id");

    return view("productpage" ,["products"=> $products]);
}
```

My blade view

```
@extends("master")
@section("mainpage")
<div class="container">
<img src="{{$products["img"]}}">
<p>{{$products["description"]}}</p>
<p>{{$products["price"]}}</p> 
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Show your results from the var_dump right before you attempt to view the image, or use `Log::info($products);` and check your log file in `/storage/logs/`

Comment: please can you share the `product model` ?

Comment: Hello SQL Injection, my old friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because `DB::select` returns an iterable (an array in Laravel versions prior to 5.3 and a Collection in later versions)

It doesn't matter that it's only a single result - it will still be an array or collection with a single value in it.

You will have to either display it in a loop, or show the first product element by index `$products[0]['img']`

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please consider using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to avoid this.

Applying this for your query looks like this

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where id = :id", ['id' => $id]);
```